# How do you pass a javascript variable as an argument to a vbscript function (in the context of HTAs)?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, javascript, hta

I am writing an HTA and I need to pass a variable that I have in Javascript to a VBScript function. Can you please let me know how to do this? Here is a (nonworking) example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE ... >
<html>
<head>    
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="chrome" APPLICATIONNAME="kiosk" ... />
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ...
        var closer =  "C:\Program Files";
        ...
    </script>
    <script language="VBScript" src="close.vbs"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onClick="VBScript:CloseExplorerWindow(window.closer)">close</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Please bear in mind that this example is waaaay oversimplified - I've just tried to strip out all the complexity and present you with what it is I'm actually trying to do.

Bonus: Is is possible to fire a VBScript function from a javascript one? My HTA uses jQuery quite extensively and it'd be nice to be able to do the system stuff I need to do from within jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a function is defined in VBScript, it can be executed from JavaScript as if it were any other globally available function.  Both scripting languages share global variables and functions.  I used to use a function so that I could access MsgBox from my JavaScript code using the following:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
Function vbsMsgBox (prompt, buttons, title)
    vbsMsgBox = MsgBox(prompt, buttons, title)
End Function
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
vbsMsgBox("This is a test", 16, "Test");
</script>
```

The order of inclusion is important when mixing these scripts.  If the first script on your page is vbscript, that becomes the default scripting engine for event handlers.  If the first is javascript, that would be the default.  Providing `vbscript:` or `javascript:` is a common misconception - in JavaScript a string followed by a colon indicates a [label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3666y5k(v=VS.85).aspx) commonly paired with loops and break/continue statements.  In VBScript, it would just cause an error.  This confusion stems with the method of running script from a URL, e.g. in the href of an `<a>` element:

```
<a href="javascript:doSomething(); void(0);">do something</a>
```

With your sample code, assuming `closer` is a global variable then your event handler should look like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="CloseExplorerWindow(closer)">close</a>
```

Also, take a look at this MSDN article on using [JScript and VBScript on the same page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260861(VS.60).aspx#vbnjscrpt_working).

Comment: Absolute legend, you are completely correct :). Thanks for the link too, that explains a lot. This is my first HTA and I haven't done a whole lot with VBScript before so this is entirely new territory for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your example should work, sure its not doing what you expect because `var closer =  "C:\Program Files";`
 should be `var closer =  "C:\\Program Files";` ?